# differentiating orders in a noun phrase

Tags: word-order

1.His **latest two** books are excellent.
2.His **two latest** books are excellent.

Could you show me the difference between these in meaning?

Thanks

Comment: Didn't you just ask about this?  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69524/how-to-distinguish-two-previous-fromprevious-two/69825#69825

Comment: In those statements, without more information about the context, there is no difference, IMHO.